# How do I get Steam to install on Debian

Tags: debian, steam

I'm a Debian user; I tried to install Steam by running `sudo apt install steam` and I typed in my password then this is what happened:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package steam
```

Comment: You need to edit your sources list first to include contrib and non-free https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-steam-client-on-debian-9-stretch-linux